# Running Junit test cases using 2 separate spring Application Context

Tags: spring, junit4

I have a set of integration JUnit test cases that I want to run under 2 or more separate spring application contexts. Application contexts differ in configuration settings and bean wirings. However, if I specify the application context file name using the **@ContextConfiguration** annotation at the top of the JUnit classes then I am only able to run these test cases once for the specified application context. Is it possible to run the same JUnit test cases with different application contexts?

Also, I am interested to execute the test cases once for each application context in the same test run - mvn test.

Answer (score 2):

Put your test code in an abstract class and use subclasses with different @ContextConfigurations.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-examples-petclinic

Answer (score 1):

You can use a master test application context file that just includes a specific context file by using Maven resource filtering

e.g.

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-context.xml")
```

where `src/main/resources/test-context.xml` is:

```
<beans>
    <import resource="${project.test.context}" />
</beans>
```

Then run `mvn test -Dproject.test.context=context1.xml`, `mvn test -Dproject.test.context=context2.xml` etc.

If you do that, you should also set a default maven property `project.test.context` in your POM.

By the way, if these are integration tests, they should by convention be called ...IT.java rather than ...Test.java, and should be run by failsafe (using `mvn verify`), not surefire.